# finding docker images with tag and name

Tags: shell-script, shell, docker

when I execute docker images I have below `docker images` as list where there are images with multiple tag and also image with latest tag value.

```
REPOSITORY                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
m1                                  latest              40febdb010b1        15 minutes ago      479MB
m2                                    130                 fab5a122127a        4 weeks ago         2.74GB
m2                                    115                 5a2ee5c5f5e5        4 weeks ago         818MB
m3                                    111                 dd91a7f68e3d        5 weeks ago         818MB
m3                                     23                  0657662756f6        5 weeks ago         2.22GB
m4                                     23                  0657662756f6        5 weeks ago         2.22GB
```

While I do `for i in {docker image save -o <imagename>.tar}` I would like to only save the images as tar for the tag with higher numbers but except any docker image with `latest` tag and docker image name as `m4`
How this can be achieved in one liner command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming bash, here’s a “one-liner” that does this:

```
unset saved; declare -A saved; docker images --format '{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}}' | while read repo tag; do if [[ "$repo" == "m4" ]] || [[ "$tag" == latest ]]; then continue; fi; if [[ "${saved[$repo]}" != true ]]; then docker image save -o "$repo-$tag".tar "$repo:$tag"; saved["$repo"]=true; fi; done
```

Split up so it’s understandable:

```
unset saved
declare -A saved
docker images --format '{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}}' | while read repo tag; do
  if [[ "$repo" == "m4" ]] || [[ "$tag" == latest ]]; then continue; fi
  if [[ "${saved[$repo]}" != true ]]; then
    docker image save -o "$repo-$tag".tar "$repo:$tag"
    saved["$repo"]=true
  fi
done
```

This declares an associative array `saved`, lists the images with only their repository and tag, skips `latest` images, and saves the image if it hasn’t already saved the repository. To determine the latter, when an image is saved, that fact is recorded in the `saved` array; before saving an image, the array is checked to see whether an image with the same repository has already been saved.

`docker images` lists the images starting with the most recent one, so this will save the most recent image whenever there are multiple images sharing the same repository (or name).

There’s no special processing of the tarball name so it might not do what you’re after with repositories containing slashes. There’s also no handling of images with no repository or tag. The following longer version creates subdirectories as appropriate and skips unlabeled images:

```
unset saved
declare -A saved
docker images --format '{{.Repository}} {{.Tag}}' | while read repo tag; do
  if [[ "$repo" == "m4" ]] || [[ "$tag" == latest ]] || [[ "$repo" == "<none>" ]] || [[ "$tag" == "<none>" ]]; then continue; fi
  if [[ "${saved[$repo]}" != true ]]; then
    if [[ "${repo}" =~ "/" ]]; then mkdir -p "${repo%/*}"; fi
    docker image save -o "$repo-$tag".tar "$repo:$tag"
    saved["$repo"]=true
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but would it always save the image with higher tag number ? also as I mentioned I would need to skip any image with repo name `m4`
here is my desired output (tars which should be saved) :
`m2-130.tar , m2-111.tar`

Comment: When multiple images share a name, this will save the most recent one. I missed the `m4` requirement, I’ll fix that.

Comment: Also I  did not understand the context of this `if [[ "${saved[$repo]}" != true ]]` will this check if the image.tar already exists in current folder and if not then it will save ?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thanks got it, it works now